# Is operating a linear transformation on an orthonormal/orthogonal base has unique properties?

Tags: linear-algebra

If i have an orthonormal/orthogonal basis $B = (v_1, v_2,...,v_n)$ in $R^n$ and a linear transformation $T: R^n \to R^n$, is doing $T(v_i), v_i \in B$ has any unique properties? unique presentations?

Comment: What kinds of properties are you looking for?

Comment: Why should it? You're not really assuming anything on $T$ here. You can always pick an orthonormal basis for $\Bbb R^n$, and so what?